# Accessing S3 bucket with a new IAM user using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

Scenario:
I have created a user and trying to access the bucket with user credentials for which i am getting InvalidAccessKey error. But if i try to access after few seconds i am getting correct response.

Below is my code

```
import boto3
import json
aws_access_key_id="xxx"
aws_secret_access_key="xxxx"
bucket_name="itsatestfornottoday"
iam_client = boto3.client('iam',region_name="us-east-1",aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
user_name = "test-user"
policy_name = "policy1"
iam_client.create_user(UserName=user_name)
policy_document = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {"Effect": "Deny", "Action": "s3:ListBucket", "Resource": "*"} }
policy_arn = iam_client.create_policy(PolicyName=policy_name, PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document))["Policy"][
    "Arn"]
iam_client.attach_user_policy(UserName=user_name, PolicyArn=policy_arn)
access_key = iam_client.create_access_key(UserName=user_name)
print(access_key)
client = boto3.client(
    "s3",
    region_name="us-east-1",
    aws_access_key_id=access_key["AccessKey"]["AccessKeyId"],
    aws_secret_access_key=access_key["AccessKey"]["SecretAccessKey"],
)

print(client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name))
```

**Error Response:**

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjects operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: `time.sleep` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> But if i try to access after few seconds i am getting correct response.

This is due to the fact that it takes some short time for IAM, and other services, **changes to propagate** throughout all AWS systems globally, and time for AWS internal caches to refresh. This is explained in more details in:

- [Changes that I make are not always immediately visible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_general.html)

> Any change that you make in IAM (or other AWS services) **takes time to become visible from all possible endpoints**. Some of the delay results from the time it takes to send the data from server to server, from replication zone to replication zone, and from Region to Region around the world. IAM also uses **caching** to improve performance, but in some cases this can add time: The change might not be visible until the previously cached data times out.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it takes some time for the user to create before you can use it. You might want to check out the Boto3 docs on Waiters.

There is [IAM.Waiter.UserExists](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Waiter.UserExists) which might be what you need.

Comment: I tried adding `waiter = iam_client.get_waiter('user_exists')
waiter.wait(UserName=user_name)` but still i am getting same response.